# Creating a list that is determined by two columns in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm having trouble figuring out how to solve my problem.
I have two columns:

```
Client Name   Job Name 
Company 1     Dealership 
Company 1     Dealership 
Company 1     Dealership 
Company 2     Airport 
Company 2     Airport 
Company 3     Dealership 
Company 3     Dealership 
Company 1     Parking Lot 
Company 1     Parking Lot
```

Using formulas (index, match, etc..) how do I make a new list
where it only lists the the unique companies and their respective job names. My new list should look like

```
Client Name   Job Name
Company 1     Dealership
Company 2     Airport 
Company 3     Dealership 
Company 1     Parking Lot
```

Basically I have a different sheet that gets populated daily with companies that we bid jobs to. We can bid the same job name to multiple companies, and we work with many of the same companies over the season. The new list needs to be dynamic as every day a new bid is sent out.

I have VBA code that works but I'm trying to do it a different way if possible

```
While Not Sheets("TempStore").Cells(x, 2).Value = ""
    'Creating comparisons for client / project name
    Set RngClient = Sheets("TempStore").Cells(x, 2)
    Set RngProject = Sheets("TempStore").Cells(x, 3)
    
    'Looping from last row to specified first row
    For LngRow = LngLastRow To (x + 1) Step -1
        'Checking conditions
        
        If Sheets("TempStore").Cells(LngRow, 2).Value = RngClient And Sheets("TempStore").Cells(LngRow, 3).Value = RngProject Then

            RngClient.Offset(0, 9).Value = RngClient.Offset(0, 9).Value + Sheets("TempStore").Cells(LngRow, 11).Value 'Total Cost
            RngProject.Offset(0, 9).Value = RngProject.Offset(0, 9).Value + Sheets("TempStore").Cells(LngRow, 12) 'Total Sell
            Sheets("TempStore").Rows(LngRow).Delete
                       
        End If
                   
    
    Next LngRow
    
    x = x + 1

Wend
```

The code above is basically used to add up a column that are associated to client name and project name then delete the row once the match is found so in the end, I'm left with a non duplicates of client per job name.

Comment: Use `RemoveDuplicates`

Comment: RemoveDuplicates will work if you only want to delete what's in those two columns.  If you need to delete the entire row then you need VBA.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb238869(v=office.12)

Comment: @Graham you can specify the whole range and then use just those two columns as the criteria and it will remove the full row based on those two columns with RemoveDuplicates and you can use Remove Duplicates in vba.

Comment: Interesting, perhaps you should post this as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: What I posted in VBA works for what I need it, but Im trying a different approach for efficiency purposes and was hoping there was a a combination of of index/match functions I could do. So its easier for the user (not having to click any buttons/etc..)